# HTTPS or JWT for authentication?

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt

I'm going to implement my authentication method using JWTs in node js.
I was searching a while for different methods of authentication and finally decide to use JWTs.
However I am confused about the JWT based authentication.

Here's my question : Should we send our JWT over HTTPS? if yes, then why should we use JWT at all ? **and why not sending all needed information over HTTPS without JWT** ?

In other words when there is security issues without HTTPS (like man-in-the-middle attack), what is the reason of using JWT for authentication purposes? is there any other authentication approach which works perfectly without using HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, you'd want to send JWT over HTTPS at all times. JWTs aren't a replacement for HTTPS, they're a replacement for server-side session data so you can run an app statelessly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you are mixing two different protocol levels.

HTTPS (or rather TLS - transport level security) is a transport layer - data transport pipe ensuring you communicate with a legitimate server and that nobody could read or change the data exchanged. HTTPS doesn't care about data itself (e. g. authentication)

JWT is commonly used as part of the  payload (data itself) describing client's identity and other attributes.

Most commonly you need both - JWT to ensure authentication or authorization and TLS/HTTPS to ensure that nobody could steal or change your JWT token or data.

HTTPS could provide client authentication, but the client needs to have its client keypair and certificate which is not really free or easy to manage  (e. g. this is how electronic ID cards work or I see it often in the server-to-server scenarios).

Comment: Thanks, As I said can we send our information in plain text over https ? if not why should we use JWT again ?

Comment: @ShahinSoft Sending it in plain text instead of encrypted in a JWT would allow a malicious client to change the data. `user_id: 1` to `user_id: 2` might let them grant themselves admin privileges, for example.

Comment: @ShahinSoft: IMHO to ensure integrity (that the client doesn't change the token) the JWT token needs to be at least signed. Many current frameworks sign the token out of box

Comment: @ceejayoz 1) when you are building an auth system based on token in case of api (not jwt, just any token) or based on session you usually checking if data belongs to the token/session and this step is a must in case you think about security 2) if malicious client got access to the data, it also got access to the components to generate jwt on the client side (malicious client could be user himself, 3d party browser, virus, plugin etc.)

Comment: @Eugene None of that is relevant to the question, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz absolutely relevant. the question was "Should we send our JWT over HTTPS?" you have explained that "YES" but i have argued to you and explained that "NO". so the answer is in case of using HTTPS using JWT is meaningless and adding unnecessary server load for decryption. but in case of HTTP using of JWT in my opinion is obligatory

Comment: @Eugene in this context we are talking https only. Using http with any kind of token (basic auth, jwt, session cookie, ..) is not secure, there is no confidentiality, integrity or authenticity guarantee. If you want to use plain http for anything important in the untrusted environment, you have to ensure the mentioned properties by other means (e.g. WS-Security)

Comment: @Eugene No one should be using plain HTTP in 2021. Certainly not for transferring JWT tokens. The server load of HTTPS is minimal, and has been for a decade.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @gusto2

JWT and HTTPS accomplish different goals. Three major components of security systems.

- C - Confidentiality - Is data secure from outsiders reading it?
- I - Integrity - Is data secure from outsiders tampering with it?
- A - Authenticity - Is data sent from the proper person

HTTPS ensures confidentiality and integrity.
JWT helps with authenticity. However, it is your job to ensure that tokens
are valid. This is not provided out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

“and why not sending all needed information over HTTPS without JWT ?”

I think the main point is that Restful or API based interaction is stateless. So in all interaction server needs to get the token to know the authenticity. And for authenticity that all requests are coming from logged in authentic user it needs to get same JWT.

Hence answer to the question in OP as Daniel said is for Authenticity.

In normal form based request we do not use token, why? Because it is stateful and we save information in session or cookies. But APIs are stateless so some token needs to be sent.